# Extjs bound html not updating when viewmodel data is changed

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, data-binding

I have a view that has the html config bound to data within my viewmodel.

#### The view

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyView',{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 300,
    controller: 'myviewcontroller',
    viewModel:{
        type: 'myviewmodel'
    },

    title: 'Testing formula updates',
    bind:{
        html: 'Date: <b>{selectedDate}</b>, <br />Month: <b>{currentMonth}</b>'
    },

    bbar:[
        {xtype: 'button', text: 'Increment Month', handler: 'onIncrementMonth'}
    ]
});
```

#### The ViewModel

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyViewModel',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.myviewmodel',

    data:{
        selectedDate: new Date()
    },
    formulas:{
        currentMonth: function (get){
            var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June","July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            var monthNumber = get('selectedDate').getMonth();
            return monthNames[monthNumber];
        }
    }

});
```

When the view is initially rendered, the bound data populates into the HTML config as expected.

I then created a method in my viewcontroller to increment the date.

#### The ViewController

```
Ext.define('MyApp.MyViewController',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.myviewcontroller',

    onIncrementMonth: function (){
        var vm = this.getViewModel();
        var dateChange = vm.get('selectedDate');

        dateChange.setMonth(dateChange.getMonth() + 1);

        vm.set('selectedDate', dateChange);
    }
});
```

I'm sure this is leading to a facepalm moment, but I was expecting that when I update the `selectedDate` data in my viewmodel, it should trigger both bound pieces of my html config to update, but it's not.

The viewmodel data is definitely updating. If you inspect the `dateChange` variable in the viewcontroller when you click the increment button the second time you'll see that the date has indeed increased.

Is there something I'm missing as far as getting my bound config to update?

I have this [here in a fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/uhg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: You need Deep Binding as @user2767141 wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37083620/139300) instead of the ugly workaround I suggested.

---

Once I changed the line:

```
vm.set('selectedDate', dateChange);
```

To:

```
vm.set('selectedDate', new Date(dateChange));
```

It works.

Comment: Awesome thanks. Why would creating a new date instance change this? Isn't `dateChange` already a date instance?

Comment: Yes, but your assigning now a new instance, this way the binding mechanism recognizes the date has been changed. I'm not quite sure this is the best solution :-)

Comment: Gotcha. Even if it's not the best solution it works and that's what I need :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Generally speaking, this is a bad solution :P The correct sollution is the deep bingind commented in other answer. The bindings are only updated when the variable in `data` are changed (an observer pattern). If you wisth to update when a subfield updates, you have to use the `deep: true`

Answer (score 4):

actually, you need Deep Binding.

ref:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewModel.

> sometimes you may need to be notified if any of the properties of that object change.

```
viewModel.bind({
     bindTo: '{someObject}',
     deep: true
 },
 function (someObject) {
     // called when reference changes or *any* property changes
 });
```